# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x\ln(n)}dx$

Tags: integration

I could have solved this by substitution, but the ‘n’ is confusing me. How should I proceed?

Comment: If you're integrating with respect to $x$ (where is the $\mbox{d}$x?), then $n$, and also $\ln n$, is just a constant... Can you integrate $\frac{1}{5\ln x}$?

Comment: Probably you misread the question. Make sure to give it another look. The variable wrt which you're supposed to integrate is missing.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add it. The question has been edited, please remove the hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question really means $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln n}$ with $n$ a constant with respect to $x$, you get $\frac{\ln |x|}{\ln n}+C=\log_n |x|+C$. If it's a typo for $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$, the substitution $u=\ln x$ gets us to the result $\ln|\ln x|+C$. (Note that in both cases the $C$ is *locally* constant.)

Comment: what does *locally* constant mean ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It's allowed to vary across asymptotes. For example, if $y^\prime=1/x$ then $y-\ln|x|$ could be $3$ for $x<0$ but $5$ for $x>0$.

Comment: sincere thanks for the explanation, @J.G.

Comment: It wasn’t mentioned in the question that n was a constant, but you are probably right, as the answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you meant '$x$' instead of '$n$', then substituting $u=\ln x$ gives $\mathrm du=\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$, and thus
$$\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}\mathrm dx=\int\frac1u\mathrm du=\ln|u|+C=\ln|\ln(x)|+C.$$

Comment: No I mean n. I checked the question twice, as I was surprised too.